# Adding new fields using hook_field_schema_alter()

Tags: entities, database

I have an entity whose field schema is already defined and now I am trying to add couple of fields to it.

But I am not sure how to code it up using schema_alter.Below is an example on how I would code the schema for the field using hook_field_schema().

```
function hook_field_schema($field){
  $columns = array(); 
  if($field['type'] == 'some_field_name'){
  $columns = array(
              'col1'=>array(
                     'type =>'text'
                     'size' => 'big'
                     'not null' => false),
              'col2'=>array(
                     'type =>'text'
                     'size' => 'big'
                     'not null' => false),
              );
  } 
 //Similar for other fields  
}
```

Confusion is on how to decompose this schema according to schema_alter.

I am following [this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/691932#comment-5371474) to implement `hook_field_schema_alter()`

**Edit:** I am using an update function to create the field (`field_create_instance`), since this is an already an existing module and I do not want to disable it and enabled it again.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call the `field_create_instance()` function passing a new array.

```
 $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_my_custom', // ** This already exists, or check with field_info_field()
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'label' => 'a label', 
    'bundle' => $content_type, 
    'widget' => array(), // if you're not sure about your widget settings, take a glimpse at an existing field instance using debug(field_info_instance(...));
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

More links to read and better understand the above functions:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7

Also, take a look at the [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples) module, node example and field example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I am trying to alter the schema of the field.I am already doing the field_create_instance using an update function.But I am unable to represent the schema information in the form according to hook_field_schema_alter.The example given is on how I would do it in hook_field_schema just for demonstration purposes